# Tool to update ASP.NET Web.config from 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I'm in the middle of updating some applications from ASP.NET 3.5 to 4.0.  The Visual Studio 2010 wizard does a nice job of converting the project file and the web.config, but I have several other web.config files for different environments (staging, production, etc.) that I also need to upgrade.

Is there a Visual Studio tool, command line utility, or other method for upgrading these web.config files?  I basically need to manually run the same wizard that Visual Studio runs automatically.

Comment: Put them in source control, then upgrade the one via VS. Then apply the patch of the changes to the others?

Comment: I could manually update each of them, but I was hoping to find a more automated way of doing it.  Plus, I have many applications that need upgrading so this could be time-consuming.

Comment: Great question, I'm looking for the same kind of tool for the same reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I never found a way to do this and ended up manually updating the config files. Once I knew the things that the wizard would do, it wasn't too hard to replicate, but it is a little tedious. Here's a good reference for what to change: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx) (see the section on manual upgrades).